# Android Camera result crash

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying to test an application, that takes a picture, and after that it will pass it to a another activity, but my APK is crash when the program wants to get in to the another activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button ButtonClicker;
    ImageView imger;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButtonClicker = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        imger = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        ButtonClicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                open();
            }
        });
    }
    public void open(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imger.setImageBitmap(bp);



    }
    }
```

The imageView4 is in the second activity. Maybe the problem is that the imageView4 is not in the MainActivity?

I can't put my MainActivity onActivityResult in the second Activity to onCreate, it's not logical. Then How to do it?

The good method would be is to pass the Main Activity result to MainActivity2 onCreate, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried using Fragment?

Comment: Correct permissions in manifest file?  How about posting the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `imageView4` is in second Activity, that would be reason of crush:
`(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);` will not find this View, so it will return `null`, you call it later -> NPE-> app crash.
First thing come to my mind, is to request saving picture in file, and then pass its Uri to second Activity via Intent (or whatever you like). Than you can put it into `imageView4`.

From http://developer.android.com/ :

```
    // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
```